# How can i check if a template is compiled out?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization

Is there a simple way to check if my template has been optimized out? After using #define HIDE_IT the code in play is below. I'm sure this code is optimized out so i get 0 overhead from defining `Property<SomeType>` but i like to check if possible (without going into assembly. Trivial code is hard enough to read after the optimizer passes through it)

```
template <class T>
class Property {
    T v;
    Property(Property&p) { }
public:
    Property() {}
    T operator=(T src) {
        v = src; return v; 
    }

    operator T() const { 
        return v;
    }
    T operator->() { return v; }
    T operator++() { return ++v; }
    template<class U>
    T operator+=(U u) { return v+=u; }
    T get() { return v; }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't even worry about it unless profiling shows it to be a performance bottleneck.

Comment: @Anycorn: Nice! i dont see any mention of it!

Comment: Compiler might create both inlined and outlined versions, staring at library binary wouldn't help. Going with a debugger through assembly will let you know what instructions are generated.

Comment: Why do you care? If the compiler has inlined all the function calls fine. If not no big deal. The compiler does its job and generates the best code it can. You should only worry about your job (which is writing the most logical maintainable code you can). As long as the logic is equivalent there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Martin: Actually running this one file my app uses up about 620mb of ram and thats after optimizing some of these things out.

Comment: so! One number is meaningless. What are the alternatives and their cost. If you are optimising for size use the size optimisers!

Comment: hmm, does size mean ram? i always thought it meant binary size. pinging @martin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no other way other than looking at the assembly. The only way it can be "optimised out" is by inlining those functions, and you can only check that by looking at the source.

That being said, on any modern compiler you can be pretty sure that those functions will be inlined in optimised code.

Comment: +1 for "modern compiler you can be pretty sure that those functions will be inlined in optimised code." -1 for being wrong about the assembly. Anycorn hit it with `nm` util on linux

Comment: @Gene: I checked nm again and it turns out i overlook it. My project has several classes that has property in it. So i created a dummy project and it indeed showed the property symbol. However it showed two with the same address (i guess its hinting its been optimized out?). +1 but i wont accept for now

Comment: I will notehowever that without HIDE_IT gcc optimizes it out anyways and i checked by using sizeof(thevar). It showed it as 4 rather then 8 which vc does in debug mode (if theres less vars then the functions uses the var must be gone as well which appears to be the case)

Comment: @acidzombie24: The symbols will be generated for the property functions whether they are inlined or not. Looking at the symbols tells you nothing about inlining.